# How to particular text replace in md files using ngx-markdown

Tags: angular, typescript, markdown

In md files +++label+++ text is avilable. So I need to replace this text with other text.
I tried with markdownService.renderer.text but text is not getting proper So I can't replace text.

how to replace this text?

`this.markdownService.renderer.text = (text: string) => { console.log('text',text); }`

Answer (score -1):

You can use the MarkedOptions object provided by the [ngx-markdown](https://github.com/jfcere/ngx-markdown#markedoptions) library to customize the renderer and replace the text you want.
You can use the renderer property of the MarkedOptions object to set a custom renderer function that will be called for each block of text in the markdown.

Here's an example of how you can use the renderer property to replace the "+++label+++" text with a different string:

```
import { MarkedOptions } from 'ngx-markdown';

const markedOptions: MarkedOptions = {
  renderer: new marked.Renderer(),
  gfm: true,
  breaks: false,
  pedantic: false,
  smartLists: true,
  smartypants: false,
};

markedOptions.renderer.text = (text: string) => {
  return text.replace(/\+\+\+label\+\+\+/g, 'REPLACED TEXT');
};

this.markdownService.setOptions(markedOptions);
```

Comment: setOptions is necessary? because setOptions is not available. I am using the 11.0 version of ngx-markdown and options are available but it's not working

Comment: stop using an old version. The current version is 15.x saying it's not working without more details is not helpful for debugging.